# for $T:U\to W$ and $A=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_k\}\subseteq U$ and $\{T(u_1),T(u_2),...,T(u_k)\}$ linearly independent set in W. prove A is linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

for $T:U\to W$ and $A=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_k\}\subseteq U$ and $\{T(u_1),T(u_2),...,T(u_k)\}$ linearly independent set in W. prove A is linear independent.

I could only prove it using the contradictive path. I'm wondering whether what I did is valid, and whether there's a more straightforward way of proving it.

$$My-proof:$$

- let there T be a linear transformation and let $A\subseteq U$ be such that ${T(u_1),T(u_2),...,T(u_k)}$ is a linearly independent set in W.
- let's assume in contradiction that A isn't linearly independent set. following that, there exist $u_i\in A$ $(i\le i\le k)$ such that exist $\lambda_j$ $(i\le j\le k)$ that fulfill: $u_i = \lambda_1u_1+\lambda_2u_2+...+\lambda_{i-1}u_{i-1}+\lambda_{i+1}u_{i+1}+...+\lambda_ku_k$.
- from the above mentioned, following that: $T(u_i)=T(\lambda_1u_1+\lambda_2u_2+...+\lambda_{i-1}u_{i-1}+\lambda_{i+1}u_{i+1}+...+\lambda_ku_k)$
  and because T is a linear transformation, it's equal to: $\lambda_1T(u_1)+\lambda_2T(u_2)+...+\lambda_{i-1}T(u_{i-1})+\lambda_{i+1}T(u_{i+1})+...+\lambda_kT(u_k)$
- so the set ${T(u_1),T(u_2),...,T(u_k)}$ is equal to
  $$\{T(u_1),T(u_2),...,\lambda_1T(u_1)+\lambda_2T(u_2)+...+\lambda_{i-1}T(u_{i-1})+\lambda_{i+1}T(u_{i+1})+...+\lambda_kT(u_k),...,T(u_k)\}$$

$\Rightarrow$ this set isn't linearly independent in contradiction to the assumption. thus, the original statements stays right. **Q.E.D**

thanks for attention and critique

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks correct to me. You don't really need to do this by contradiction though. You have basically proved the contrapositive statement with your argument: If $A$ is not linearly independent, then $\{T(u_1), ..., T(u_k)\}$ is also not linearly independent. The contrapositive is logically equivalent to your original question and its always nicer to have a proof without contradiction if you can avoid it.

The direct proof is also similar. As a hint, suppose there are scalars $a_1, ..., a_k$ such that $a_1u_1 + ... + a_ku_k = 0$. What happens now if you plug in $a_1u_1 + ... + a_ku_k$ into $T$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be the subspace generated by $A$ and $F$ the subspace
generated by $f (A)$, let $g$ the linear map from $E$ to $F$
obtained by restriction of $f$ to $E$ , then $k\geq dimE = rank
(A)$ and $inf(dimE,dimF)\geq  rank (g (A)) = rank ( f (A))=k$ by
assumption that $rank (f (A))$ is $ k$, so $rank(A)=k$ therefor
$A$ is a free system.

Comment: I couldn't understand the notations you used. what does mean $inf(dimE,dimF)$ and "free system"? by the way, what do you think about my proof?

Comment: this is another easy proof.

Comment: inf(n,m)  yhis is the smaller of n and m, A is a set of vectors is free mean the vectors in A are linzarly independant, sorry for my englisch and yhanks

Comment: your demonstration is correct, but you should have to show instead
of $T (u_i)$ in the last writing or suppose that $i=1$ no problem; thanks